# How can i get width and height from href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, height, width

[image: screenshot]

i need to get this values using VANILLA javascript - 786 x 587 
thanks

Comment: did You provide image URL into a href attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get image height and width from href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352330/how-to-get-image-height-and-width-from-href)

Answer (score 0):

- document.querySelector('a[href="link"]').clientWidth
- document.querySelector('a[href="link"]').clientHeight

Comment: it's still not a size that i want

Answer (score 0):

here is  the code snippet

```
function getImageHeight(link)
{
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "http://picscdn.redblue.de/doi/pixelboxx-mss-76800921/fee_786_587_png/DURACELL-Duracell-BSC-4-db-AA-elem" || link
console.log(img.height)
console.log(img.width)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a regex. in the case shown below the `console.log` will return the values of the `width` and `height` of your URL

```
<body>
<a id="tag" href="http://asdfasdfasdf.derp/foo_300x500.png"></a>
<script>
var link = document.getElementById("tag").href;
// pattern for the regex
var pattern = /foo_(\d*)x(\d*).png/g
var result = new RegExp(pattern).exec(link);
console.log(result[1]); // returns first digits (width)
console.log(result[2]); // returns second digits (height)
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to cache the element before accessing its attributes

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('t')[0]; document.write(element.getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a class='t' href='value-im-looking-for'>link</a>
<br>
result:
```

Comment: its easier to get the value if you use a unique id as you don't have to get the array index